# creating nested xml using ms sql query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xsd

I've a table T1 with following fields: ID,Surname, Name, BirthDate, BirthPlace, DocNumber, IssueDate.
I've created xml by

```
select * from T1
for XML PATH ('Person')
```

This created me xml with following format

```
<Person>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <SurName>Ivanov</SurName>
   ...
</Person>
<Person>
...
</Person>
...
```

This XML contains only one element, which is 'Person', I want to create another element ('Documents') inside this element, similar to:

```
<Person>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <SurName>Ivanov</SurName>
   ...
   <Documents>
      <DocNumber>1234</DocNumber>
      <IssueDate>'20140101'</IssueDate>
   </Documents>
</Person>
...
```

How can I do this? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Sample data

```
ID SurName Name BirthDate  BirthPlace DocNumber IssueDate
1  Ivanov  Ivan '19900212' Moscow     1111      '20121225'
1  Ivanov  Ivan '19900212' Moscow     2222      '20110629'
2  Smirnov Petr '19851006' Kazan      3333      '20090601'
2  Smirnov Petr '19851006' Kazan      4444      '20130930'
```

Comment: Can you share the `schema` and `sample data` of `T1` table

Comment: Thanks to everybody. This was helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658942/sql-server-for-xml-path-nesting-grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the FOR XML PATH option that SQL Server 2005 introduced - see the [What's New in FOR XML in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137(v=sql.90).aspx#forxml2k5_topic6) document for more information.

Basically, with FOR XML PATH, you can define the shape of your XML very easily. You can define certain structures, you can define certain columns to be output as attributes, and others as elements - totally under your control.

Not knowing your table structure, I can only guess what the tables and columns are called in your case - but you could probably write something like:

```
    Select 
          tt1.ID AS 'ID',
          tt1.Surname As 'Surname',
          ...
          ( 
            Select 
                 tt2.DocNumber As 'DocNumber',
                 tt2.Issudate AS 'IssueDate',
            From 
                 T1 as tt2 WITH(NOLOCK)
            Where
                 tt2.ID = tt1.ID
            for xml path('Documents'), type
           )
     From
         t1 as tt1 
     For xml path ('Person')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery to provide the nesting required:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c042/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
        ([ID] int, [SurName] varchar(7), [Name] varchar(4), 
         [BirthDate] datetime, [BirthPlace] varchar(6), 
         [DocNumber] int, [IssueDate] datetime)
    ;

INSERT INTO T1
    ([ID], [SurName], [Name], [BirthDate], [BirthPlace], [DocNumber], [IssueDate])
VALUES
    (1, 'Ivanov', 'Ivan', '1990-02-12 00:00:00', 'Moscow', 1111, '2012-12-25 00:00:00'),
    (1, 'Ivanov', 'Ivan', '1990-02-12 00:00:00', 'Moscow', 2222, '2011-06-29 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Smirnov', 'Petr', '1985-10-06 00:00:00', 'Kazan', 3333, '2009-06-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Smirnov', 'Petr', '1985-10-06 00:00:00', 'Kazan', 4444, '2013-09-30 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT [ID], [SurName], [Name], [BirthDate], [BirthPlace],
(SELECT [DocNumber], [IssueDate] 
 FROM T1 AS T2
 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
 FOR XML PATH ('Document'), type)
FROM T1
GROUP BY [ID], [SurName], [Name], [BirthDate], [BirthPlace]
FOR XML PATH ('Person')
```

Produces:

```
<Person>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <SurName>Ivanov</SurName>
  <Name>Ivan</Name>
  <BirthDate>1990-02-12T00:00:00</BirthDate>
  <BirthPlace>Moscow</BirthPlace>
  <Document>
    <DocNumber>1111</DocNumber>
    <IssueDate>2012-12-25T00:00:00</IssueDate>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <DocNumber>2222</DocNumber>
    <IssueDate>2011-06-29T00:00:00</IssueDate>
  </Document>
</Person>
<Person>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <SurName>Smirnov</SurName>
  <Name>Petr</Name>
  <BirthDate>1985-10-06T00:00:00</BirthDate>
  <BirthPlace>Kazan</BirthPlace>
  <Document>
    <DocNumber>3333</DocNumber>
    <IssueDate>2009-06-01T00:00:00</IssueDate>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <DocNumber>4444</DocNumber>
    <IssueDate>2013-09-30T00:00:00</IssueDate>
  </Document>
</Person>
```