# How to write a FULL XML record to column based on row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xp-cmdshell, for-xml-path

I have a stored procedure that I am using to write custom XML based on a vendors requirements for integrating two systems. I would like to write each record to a column to bypass the char limitation in a sql column. I am including a very simple version of my SP. I have 600 fields in the true SP. I have 4700 records in the table and my XML is getting cut off after 200 rows process. Is there a way to return everything between the Command action="Upsert" invalidLookupBehavior="Skip" and the "/Command" in their own columns?
I'm stumped. I apologize for the duplicate post.. TAB

```
USE [DEV]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MASTER_TABLE_XML_PHASE_I]   ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MASTER_TABLE_XML_PHASE_I_SIMPLE]
AS
declare
@xml nvarchar(max),
@metaEMPLOYEE nvarchar(max)

CREATE TABLE #MASTER_TABLE_IMPORT
(
[EMP_COMPANY_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[EMP_LAST_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EMP_MIDDLE_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EMP_FIRST_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EMP_PREFIX] [nchar](6) NULL,
[EMP_PREFERRED_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EMP_FORMER_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[IMP_CREATE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
[IMP_LAST_UPDATE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
)

INSERT INTO #MASTER_TABLE_IMPORT
(
[EMP_COMPANY_ID] ,
[EMP_LAST_NAME] ,
[EMP_MIDDLE_NAME] ,
[EMP_FIRST_NAME],
[EMP_PREFIX] ,
[EMP_PREFERRED_NAME],
[EMP_FORMER_NAME] ,
[EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER] ,
[IMP_CREATE_DATE],
[IMP_LAST_UPDATE_DATE]
)

SELECT
EMP_COMPANY_ID ,
EMP_LAST_NAME,
EMP_MIDDLE_NAME ,
EMP_FIRST_NAME,
EMP_PREFIX ,
EMP_PREFERRED_NAME,
EMP_FORMER_NAME ,
T1.EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER,
IMP_CREATE_DATE,
IMP_LAST_UPDATE_DATE

FROM MASTER_TABLE_PHASE_I AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER ,MAX(IMP_CREATE_DATE) AS MaxDate
FROM MASTER_TABLE_PHASE_I
GROUP BY EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER) AS T2
ON (T1.EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER = T2.EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER AND T1.IMP_CREATE_DATE =     T2.MaxDate)
/*OPEN XML FULL FILE TAGS*/
set @xml =
N'<DataChange><Commands>'
+ N'' + CHAR(10);

/*OPEN EMPLOYEE TABLE*/
/*OPEN EMPLOYEE FIELDS*/

select @metaEMPLOYEE =
CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
(
(select
/*OPEN XML UNIQUE RECORD TAGS*/
'<Command action="Upsert" invalidLookupBehavior="Skip"><Tables><Table     name="EMPLOYEE"><Fields>'+
'<Field name="COMPANY_ID" lookupValue="False">84</Field>',
'<Field name="LAST_NAME">' + EMP_LAST_NAME + '</Field>',
'<Field name="MIDDLE_NAME">' + EMP_MIDDLE_NAME + '</Field>',
'<Field name="FIRST_NAME">' + EMP_FIRST_NAME + '</Field>',
'<Field name="PREFIX" lookupValue="True">' + EMP_PREFIX + '</Field>',
'<Field name="PREFERRED_NAME">' + EMP_PREFERRED_NAME + '</Field>',
'<Field name="FORMER_NAME">' + EMP_FORMER_NAME + '</Field>',
'<Field name="SYSTEM_NUMBER" recordIdentifier="True">' + EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER +         '</Field>',
/*CLOSE EMPLOYEE FIELDS*/
'</Fields>',
/*CLOSE EMPLOYEE TABLE*/
'</Table>',
/*CLOSE EMPLOYEE RECORD ALL TABLES*/
'</Tables>',
/*CLOSE XML COMMAND*/
/*CLOSE XML UNIQUE RECORD TAGS*/
'</Command>'
FROM #MASTER_TABLE_IMPORT
WHERE 1=1

FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')))
/*BUILD XML*/
/*CLOSING MASTER COMMAND*/
/*CLOSING MASTER DATA CHANGE*/

SET @xml = @xml + @metaEMPLOYEE +'</Commands></DataChange>'
SELECT @xml;

CREATE TABLE XMLDATA
(
xCol XML
) ;

INSERT INTO XMLDATA ( xCol )
SELECT @xml


DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Filename VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @Filename = 'C:\Client_XML\Data.dat'

SELECT @Command = 'bcp "select xCol from ' + DB_NAME()
+ '..XMLDATA" queryout '
+ @Filename + ' -w -T -S' + @@servername
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @command
--WRITE THE XML TO A FILE

SELECT CONVERT(nVARCHAR(max),BulkColumn)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Client_XML\Data.dat', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x

DROP TABLE XMLDATA
```

Thank you Shnugo. I'm not a SQL developer. Unfortunately we have a resource issue and so I thought I would give this a try. I understand enough to be dangerous and ask questions correctly. This is so much better. Thank you, thank you. There are only a handful of fields in this example (I have nearly 600 fields and 4700 records to process every 15 minutes, hence the need for this). When I run this, the XML is still truncated at row 1200. Is there a way to take the @myXML results and parse to columns base on the the row id of the data source? One row? Is there a column number limitation in a SQL table?  Here is a screen shot of what I would expect this table to look like. 
[SQL Table concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCLcZ.gif)

Thank you for your help and you patience.
Pennie

I am determining that it is truncated in two ways.
1- I am saving the file to a folder on my HD using xp_cmd_shell
2- I have saved the results from my query.

This is the last record in the returned file row 1200

```
<Command action="Upsert" invalidLookupBehavior="Skip"><Tables><Table name="EMPLOYEE" /><Fields><Field name="COMPANY_ID" lookupValue="False">84</Field><Field name="LAST_NAME">Auditore</Field><Field name="MIDDLE_NAME" /><Field name="FIRST_NAME">Ezio</Field><Field name="PREFIX" loo
```

ends right there. 
Pennie

Hi Shnugo. How do I add Child Nodes ==> ChildTables to your concept? I just keep getting errors. 
The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a ASSIGNMENT statement.

This is what the XML result should look like. I also have ChildTables nested in ChildTables.

```
<Command action="Upsert" invalidLookupBehavior="Skip"><Tables><Table name="EMPLOYEE"><Fields><Field name="COMPANY_ID" lookupValue="False">84</Field><Field name="LAST_NAME">Pinot</Field><Field name="FIRST_NAME">Gris</Field><Field name="PREFIX" lookupValue="True">Ms.</Field><Field name="SYSTEM_NUMBER" recordIdentifier="True">1603-XXXXX</Field><Field name="GENDER" lookupValue="True">Female</Field><Field name="MARITAL_STATUS" lookupValue="True">Married</Field><Field name="BIRTH_COUNTRY" lookupValue="True">Guatemala</Field><Field name="USER_ID_EMAIL">gris.pinot@me.com</Field></Fields><ChildTables><Table name="EMPLOYEE_CF"><Fields><Field name="CF_TEXT001">Gris</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT002">Pinot</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT003">Pinot</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT026">Family</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT027">No</Field><Field name="CF_NUMBER001">2</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="EMPLOYEE_PASSPORT"><Fields><Field name="ISSUE_COUNTRY" lookupValue="True">Guatemala</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="ASSIGNMENT"><Fields><Field name="NUMBER" recordIdentifier="True">1603-XXXXX</Field><Field name="FROM_COUNTRY" lookupValue="True">United Arab Emirates</Field><Field name="TO_COUNTRY" lookupValue="True">Malaysia</Field><Field name="TYPE" lookupValue="True">Long Term</Field><Field name="PHASE" lookupValue="True">New Assignment</Field><Field name="SCHEDULED_END_DATE">04/30/2019</Field><Field name="FROM_COMPANY_LEVEL1">From Level1</Field><Field name="FROM_COMPANY_LEVEL2">From Level2</Field><Field name="FROM_COMPANY_LEVEL3">From Level3</Field><Field name="FROM_COMPANY_LEVEL4">From Level4</Field><Field name="TO_COMPANY_LEVEL1">To Level1</Field><Field name="TO_COMPANY_LEVEL2">To Level2</Field><Field name="TO_COMPANY_LEVEL3">To Level3</Field><Field name="TO_COMPANY_LEVEL4">To Level4</Field></Fields><ChildTables><Table name="ASSIGNMENT_CF"><Fields><Field name="CF_TEXT002">No</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT005">1234567</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT009">1111111</Field><Field name="CF_TEXT010">2222222</Field><Field name="CF_DATE004">03/22/2016</Field><Field name="CF_DATE005">03/23/2016</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="ASSIGNMENT_EMPLOYEE_CONTACT"><Fields><Field name="LOCATION_TYPE" recordIdentifier="true">Current Address</Field><Field name="CONTACT_TYPE" recordIdentifier="true">Address</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="ASSIGNMENT_CONTACT"><Fields><Field name="TYPE" recordIdentifier="true">Manager</Field><Field name="NAME">Trinity</Field><Field name="EMAIL">trinity@me.com.com</Field><Field name="PHONE">5555555555</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="ASSIGNMENT_CONTACT"><Fields><Field name="TYPE" recordIdentifier="true">Home HR Contact</Field><Field name="NAME">Kim</Field><Field name="EMAIL">kim.@me.com</Field><Field name="PHONE">5555555551</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="ASSIGNMENT_CONTACT"><Fields><Field name="TYPE" recordIdentifier="true">HR Contact</Field><Field name="NAME">Pennie</Field><Field name="EMAIL">me@me.com</Field><Field name="PHONE">5555555552</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="ASSIGNMENT_MAILING_ADDRESS"><Fields><Field name="LOCATION_TYPE" recordIdentifier="true">Home Address</Field> </Fields></Table><Table name="POLICY"><Fields><Field name="NAME">424</Field></Fields></Table><Table name="UT_ACCOUNT_SPECIFIC_MISC_COMP_DATA"><Fields><Field name="HOME_BUSINESS_FUNCTION">Finance</Field><Field name="HOST_BUSINESS_FUNCTION">Finance</Field><Field name="EST_ASSIGNMENT_START_DATE">07/01/2016</Field></Fields></Table></ChildTables></Table></ChildTables></Table></Tables></Command>
```

I appreciate the help. 
Pennie
4/5
@Shnugo This is still unresolved as I am not able to use @command. The other part of this is I cannot write the XML from the result set. It is custom. The result set is coming from a system I do not own. Though this was all extremely helpful. I am working with the suggestions. I would like to vote as you were very responsive and so knowledgeable. Maybe because I am so new I am not able to vote. Regardless, I am not clear on how to vote. 
P

Comment: How are you determining that it is truncated?

Comment: Hi Pennie! As you are new here, please allow me some hints: If found your  additions by chance, because I tend to actively come back to questions where I gave an answer still standing unclosed. The edit option is meant to add something to your question. In your case - at least part of this - should have been a comment below my answer. If you add the user's name with an "at" (e.g. `@Shnugo`) this will trigger an alert. I'll add a second comment to answer your questions.

Comment: Edit1 (Truncation): Try a right click into your query window, then options. Search for the grid options. There is a size limit for XML. You can set this to unlimited. In this case only your hardware sets the limit. By clicking on an XML's result you will enter the XML Viewer which will show you the whole thing. If not, please come back...

Comment: Edit2 (deepter nestings): Your example includes more nested nodes. You achieve this walking from outside to inside. Add a simple statement to your query which does not more than to add the empty node `,(SELECT 'test' AS TestNode FOR XML PATH('RowName'),TYPE) AS ElementName`. Play around with the namings, try with `AS [*]` to find out how this works. Be sure, that there is a `,TYPE` at the end. When the node is there, you fill it with the data needed. Here's an easy example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11658942/5089204

Comment: Hi @Shnugo what if I solve my own issue? I have a couple of questions that I resolved on my own. It looks like you can't vote on your own :-)

Comment: @Plane Well... No... Reputation points are a value to reflect what *other* SO users think about your contributions. There are two levels of "payment": rep points and badges. you get points when you ask a well recieved question (others vote it up) or for a well recieved answer or if your answer is accepted (but not a self answer ... ). You get badges for certain progress on SO and - very important - *tag badges* if you get many upvotes on a certain topic. Just read through the SO sites ...

Comment: @Plane one more thing: Yes, you are allowed to answer your own question (There's even a badge for it: "self learner") but the votes must come from other users. If no given answer helps you, but you find one yourself, it is even recommended to poste your answer for future readers. There's a gap of some days before you are allowed to accept a self-answer, but you should do this, if it solves the issue. If it's voted you might get the badge :-)

Comment: @Shnugo - I will spend some time this weekend and read through SO. It has been extremely helpful to me while trying to pick up some new skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a huge lot of unnecessary work...

- It seems that you do not need your temp table
- You should **never** build your XML as string via string concatenation
- The result returned by `SELECT ... FOR XML` has (almost) no limit in size
- Size restrictions are - in most cases - bound to intermediate steps / conversions / computations / whatever, where the return type is not big enough

If you go like this, the whole result is in `@myXML`. 
From there you can continue however you like...

```
DECLARE @myXML XML;

WITH CTE_instead_of_TempTable AS
(
    SELECT  EMP_COMPANY_ID ,
            EMP_LAST_NAME,
            EMP_MIDDLE_NAME ,
            EMP_FIRST_NAME,
            EMP_PREFIX ,
            EMP_PREFERRED_NAME,
            EMP_FORMER_NAME ,
            T1.EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER,
            IMP_CREATE_DATE,
            IMP_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    --This is the source you are using to fill your temp table. Cannot know, wheter it's correct or not
    --The two "FROM" lines are disturbing...
    FROM MASTER_TABLE_PHASE_I AS T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER ,MAX(IMP_CREATE_DATE) AS MaxDate
    FROM MASTER_TABLE_PHASE_I
    GROUP BY EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER) AS T2
    ON (T1.EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER = T2.EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER AND T1.IMP_CREATE_DATE =     T2.MaxDate)
)
SELECT @myXML=
(
    SELECT
    (
     SELECT
         'Upsert'               AS [@action]
        ,'Skip'                 AS [@invalidLookupBehavior]
        ,(
            SELECT 
                'EMPLOYEE'             AS [Table/@name]
               ,(
                    SELECT
                         'COMPANY_ID'           AS [Field/@name]
                        ,'False'                AS [Field/@lookupValue]
                        ,84                     AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'LAST_NAME'            AS [Field/@name]
                        ,EMP_LAST_NAME          AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'MIDDLE_NAME'          AS [Field/@name]
                        ,EMP_MIDDLE_NAME        AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'FIRST_NAME'           AS [Field/@name]
                        ,EMP_FIRST_NAME         AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'PREFIX'               AS [Field/@name]
                        ,'True'                 AS [Field/@lookupValue]
                        ,EMP_PREFIX             AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'PREFERRED_NAME'       AS [Field/@name]
                        ,EMP_PREFERRED_NAME     AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'FORMER_NAME'          AS [Field/@name]
                        ,EMP_FORMER_NAME        AS [Field]
                        ,''
                        ,'SYSTEM_NUMBER'        AS [Field/@name]
                        ,'True'                 AS [Field/@recordIdentifier]
                        ,EMP_SYSTEM_NUMBER      AS [Field]
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                ) AS [Fields]
            FOR XML PATH('Tables'),TYPE
          ) 
        FROM CTE_instead_of_TempTable
        FOR XML PATH('Command'),TYPE
      )
    FOR XML PATH('Commands'),ROOT('DataChange'),TYPE
)

SELECT @myXML;
```