# XML Column Output

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, vb.net

I am working on a console program to generate an XML file using a SQL Server database and .NET.

Currently, I am stuck with my code to generate a proper XML file. As my `Categories` node are not properly identified as XML format when I open the file in Notepad and as a result, am unable to consume it well.

What is needed is this:

1. Generate a proper XML tags for `Categories` as below & shouldn't include any special characters when opening in any notepad.
2. If I have multiple site ID (locations), how I can do a for loop from my SQL table against my code.

   ```
    Dim dsXmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Inv"
    dsXmlDoc.LoadXml(ds.GetXml())

    Dim xmlInner As XmlElement = CType(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/"),
    XmlElement)xmlInner.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(dsXmlDoc.DocumentElement, True))
   ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : FOR XML PATH - nesting / grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658942/sql-server-for-xml-path-nesting-grouping)

Comment: Looks like your query is effectivcely generating a string that looks like XML/encoding XML needlessly, and youre trying to add this into an XML node, so it has to be escaped to stop it being interpreted as XML, when really you wanted it as part of the XML structure. You'll need to remove the casting, among other things (doesn't help that you posted an incomplete SQL). See the linked duplicate

Comment: The CAST categories (xml) as VARCHAR ain't gonna help! Do you understand why?

Comment: You'll probably need to structure this a bit differently.. Getting it completely right without having something to test on will be a challenge, but I'll give it a go

Answer (score 1):

I think it'll be this:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT 
    A.[ORDER ID],
    RIGHT(A.[POS ID], 2) AS [LesseePOSNumber],
    REPLACE(A.[BUSINESS DATE],'-','') + '-' + A.[RECEIPT NUMBER] AS [InvoiceNumber],
    '1' AS [DocumentType],
    CAST(A.[BUSINESS DATE] AS datetime) + CAST(A.[START SALE TIME] AS DATETIME) AS [TransactionDateTime],
    SUM(A.ITEM) AS [TotalNumberOfItems],
    SUM(A.[TOTAL AMOUNT] - A.[TOTAL TAX]) AS [TransactionTotalWithoutVAT],
    SUM(A.[TOTAL TAX]) AS [VATTotalAmount],
    '1' AS [PaymentType],
    '4' AS [Currency]
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
           T1.[storeId] AS [STORE NO]
          ,CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar(15),T1.businessDate,101)) AS [BUSINESS DATE]
          ,FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING(T1.startSaleTime,1,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(T1.startSaleTime,3,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(T1.startSaleTime,5,2), 121), 'h:mm:ss') AS [START SALE TIME]
          ,CASE WHEN (T1.Type) = 'TRX_Refund' OR (T1.Type) = 'TRX_Overring' THEN CAST(T1.[totalAmount] AS decimal(16,2)) * -1 ELSE CAST(T1.[totalAmount] AS decimal(16,2)) END AS [TOTAL AMOUNT]
          ,CASE WHEN (T1.Type) = 'TRX_Refund' OR (T1.Type) = 'TRX_Overring' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [GC] 
          ,CASE WHEN (T1.Type) = 'TRX_Refund' OR (T1.Type) = 'TRX_Overring' THEN CAST(T1.[totalTax] AS decimal(16,2)) * -1 ELSE CAST(T1.[totalTax] AS decimal(16,2)) END AS [TOTAL TAX]     
          ,T1.NodeId AS [POS ID]
          ,T1.[receiptNumber] AS [RECEIPT NUMBER]
          ,T1.orderId AS [ORDER ID]
          ,
          (
            SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(T2.totalPrice AS float) > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            FROM [McDonalds_STG].[dbo].[ITEMLEVEL] T2
            WHERE T2.orderId = T1.orderId
          ) AS [ITEM]

    FROM [McDonalds_STG].[dbo].[Orders] T1

  ) A

  GROUP BY
    A.[STORE NO],
    A.[BUSINESS DATE],
    A.[POS ID],
    A.[RECEIPT NUMBER],
    A.[START SALE TIME],
    A.[ORDER ID]
)
SELECT 
  x.[LesseePOSNumber],
  x.[InvoiceNumber],
  x.[DocumentType],
  x.[TransactionDateTime],
  x.[TotalNumberOfItems],
  x.[TransactionTotalWithoutVAT],
  x.[VATTotalAmount],
  x.[PaymentType],
  x.[Currency], 
  (
    SELECT 
      49 AS [ID],
      (CAST(T1.[totalAmount] AS decimal(16,2)) - CAST(T1.[totalTax] AS decimal(16,2)) ) AS [Total]
    FROM [Order] T2  
    WHERE T2.orderId = x.[ORDER ID]  
    FOR XML PATH('Category'), TYPE 
  ) As Categories
FROM x
FOR XML PATH ('Invoice'), root ('Invoices')
```

There are still some opportunities here for significant, sensible refactoring here (the date/string/date handling needs throwing away and doing again without using strings where possible), and it might need some typos fixing; it's not an easy SQL to read and I don't expect it'll just paste straight into SSMS and work without some tweaks!

Note that you GROUP BY STORE NO but you don't appear to use it

Comment: Because what you saved it with/what you did with it when you "managed to get the output" converted the result to string, and then when saved as xml, resulted in an encoded string, as a guess.. I can't really do anything with the information you gave - there is nowhere near enough info to debug what is going on. If the query produces the required XML as XML then your problem is elsewhere (out of the scope of this question, which was to "fix the SQL". Post a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example as a new question)

Comment: Note that your original query produces strings that you later build into XML in VB (i guess).. My SQL produces XML (which you shouldn't then try to eg turn into a string and then turn into XML again in your VB)

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("Invoice")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("LesseePOSNumber"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            string lesseePOSNumber = "1";
            string id = "29";
            int total = 3000;
            if (dict.ContainsKey(lesseePOSNumber))
            {
                XElement categories = new XElement("Categories", new XElement("Category", new object[] {
                    new XElement("ID", id),
                    new XElement("Total", total)
                }));

                dict[lesseePOSNumber].Add(categories);
            }
 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yuu are getting a string so use parse instead of load : XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(string);